# set jQuery autocomplete match criteria?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've written a page with a jQuery UI autocomplete.

The user is meant to use the autocomplete to select a location from a list of places.  Prior to this improvement, the user had to select a location from a long list, and this would be much better except for one problem.

The locations are formatted like this:

"Canada"

"Canada -> Alberta"

"Canada -> British Colombia"

"United States"

"United States -> Alabama"

"United States -> Alaska"

and so on.  So, I tested this application by typing in "CA" expecting a list countries and states that beging with "CA" like: "Canada", "United States -> California", "Mexico -> Campeche".

However, much to my dismay, I see all the Canadian provinces listed one by one because the "CA" matches the "CA" in "Canada".  I now have almost twenty options to choose from.

The user must see the hierarchy with the name of the country and the name of the state when looking up a state, but "Canada" as a country must be a single match as a single location.

How can I set up jQuery autocomplete to allow me to specify in so many words that only the text to the right of the "->" is to be matched?

Right now, in my Javascript code, I have
var locations = "[{'label':'Canada','value','Canada'},{'label':'Canada -> Alberta', 'value':'Alberta'}...].

I do not want to make this work asynchronously.  I fear it would result in way too many web service calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  It helps to have a good jQuery UI reference!

For the source variable of the .autocomplete method, you can pass in the autocomplete data, or you can pass in a handler to a function to retrieve the autocomplete options, like so:

```
$('#txtData').autocomplete( source: getData )
```

The handler function will be passed two arguments, the first is an object with one field: `term` which contains the text that the user entered.  The other is a handler to yet another function.  This other function takes one parameter, which is the data containing the autocomplete options:

```
function getData(userData, setAutocompleteData) {
    var userText = userData.term;
    var autocompleteData = getMatchingOptions(userText);
    // getMatchingOptions returns a list of matching autocomplete options
    setAutocompleteData(autocompleteData);
}
```

The code skeleton above combined with your implementation of `getMatchingOptions` should allow you to customize what autocomplete options are shown to the user.

Comment: I answered my own question for whoever marked this as "favorite"